# ColumnFixture Errors with variables

Tags: fitnesse, fit-framework

Having some issues with variables of format `>>variableName<<` within column fixtures in FitNesse. The language being used is C#. These errors are very similar to the parser error issue that was resolved recently. If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about solving the issue, or a resolution that would be great.

The specific issue is illegal characters in the table. variables in this format are not translated to their specific values... they are passed through as `>>varName<<`, with `>>` and `<<` included.

Comment: Adam, I would recommend that you ask questions like this on the yahoo group rather than here.  Technically the yahoo group is the best place for tech support, as I know it goes right into the mailboxes of people who develop stuff like FitSharp.  Mike does come by here, but I don't know how often.  I'm not really a c# user, so I don't know the nuances of FitSharp variables.  If you are going to post this here, or even on the yahoo group, I recommend that you phrase your title as a question and you supply a better example of the table that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names wont work, instead try the following as an example.

First create a column fixture 'ShouldIncreaseCustomerCreditLimit' with input parameters AccountNumber and CreditLimit and output param CaseNumber.
Then create 'ShouldLoadCaseDetailsByCaseNumber' column fixture that takes input CaseNumber and output CreditLimit and AccountNumber.

In the wiki add the column fixture.

```
!|ShouldIncreaseCustomerCreditLimit          |
|AccountNumber      |CreditLimit|=CaseNumber?|
|0001011190301064616|1000       |>>casenumber|


!|ShouldLoadCaseDetailsByCaseNumber           |
|CaseNumber= |CreditLimit?|AccountNumber?     |
|<<casenumber|1000        |0001011190301064616|
```

Hope this helps.

Regards
Rustin